# Roxygen2 S4 slot inheritance

Tags: r, roxygen2

I am writing a new S4 class that contains the slots from another class in another package:

```
#' Example 1
#' @slot A0 variable A0
#' @slot B0 variable B0
#' @exportClass Ex1
setClass("Ex1", slots=c(A0 = "matrix", B0 = "matrix"),
                prototype=prototype(A0 = matrix(),
                                    B0 = matrix()))

# and in another package:

#' Example 2
#' @slot A variable A
#' @slot B variable B
#' @exportClass Ex2
setClass("Ex2", slots=c(A = "matrix", B = "matrix"),
                prototype=prototype(A = matrix(),
                                    B = matrix()),
                contains = c("Ex1"))
```

Using roxygen2, I would like for class Ex2 to inherit the slot documentation from class Ex1. I know you can do this for parameters with `@inheritParams package::function`. Is there an equivalent way for S4 slots?

Comment: Did you every find a solution to this?